# LibGDX - How to center an Isometric Tiled Map on screen?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, isometric

I've been tinkering around with LibGDX for a few days now. I've managed to render an Isometric Tiled Map onto the screen but I just can't seem to figure out how to center it properly. Here's the code:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {

    private TiledMap map;
    private IsometricTiledMapRenderer isometricRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    public void createUI() {
        // Load map from tiled .tmx file.
        map = new TmxMapLoader().load("arena1/arena1.tmx");

        // Setup isometric renderer and camera.
        isometricRenderer = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(map);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
        createUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        isometricRenderer.setView(camera);
        isometricRenderer.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = width;
        camera.viewportHeight = height;
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public void hide() {}

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        isometricRenderer.dispose();
    }

}
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Tiled map](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TiledMap.html) hasn't `setPosition`  method or something like this. So what you should do is move your camera.

Call this in your render method to move your camera by WASD:

```
private void cameraController(Camera camera){

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) {
       camera.translate(0, 10, 0);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)) {
       camera.translate(0, -10, 0);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) {
       camera.translate(-10, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) {
       camera.translate(10, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

You can also change 10 to speed which you want.

Or if you don't want to move it by WASD you can just set position directly.

```
camera.setPosition(x, y, z);
```

Comment: I tried out camera.setPosition() before posting but I couldn't get it to center, what should I use as parameters?

Comment: @MartimFerreira maybe your map width and height divided by 2?

Comment: @MartimFerreira if my answer solved your problem please mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help. But eventually I managed to find a solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with

```
camera.position.set(768, 0, 0);
```

768 is half the width of the map.